# Asp.net Not geting value from javascript function in c# variable

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

this problem has wasted much of my time. I have written a javascript function and assigned value to asp hidden field but when i run my application i am not getting the value in c# variable 
please correct me if i am missing something.
thanks in advance.
here is my code
javascript function:

```
function sureDelete() {
            if (confirm("DELETE USER?") == true) {              
                document.getElementById("hidden_yesno").setAttribute("Value", "1");
              //document.getElementById('deleteYesNo').value = 1;
            } else {                         
                document.getElementById("hidden_yesno").setAttribute("Value", "0");
               //document.getElementById('deleteYesNo').value = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

my hidden field and click event

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden_yesno" runat="server" />
<asp:ImageButton  runat="server" CssClass="pt-userDeactive help" CommandName="deleteuser"
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("user_id") %>' ImageUrl ="../TemplateS/assets/images/delete.png"
Width="25px" Height="25px" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" OnClientClick="return sureDelete()"/>
```

and following is the c# code

```
 protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) {
            string flag = hidden_yesno.Value.ToString();
              //here i am getting the value as: ""            
            if (flag == "1") {
               //do something
            } else {
                //do nothing
            }          
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `asp:HiddenFeild` whose `ID` is changed by `asp.net` according to `ContentPlaceHolder` so it is not found by javascript/jquery.

Either you need exact `ID` of hidden feild or you can set `ClientIDMode="static"` which will make sure that `ID` is not changed.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden_yesno" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```